# What is the difference between a compact space and bounded space?

Tags: compactness, upper-lower-bounds

I understand them separately. I am trying to contrast them. What properties separate them? Are there nontrivial examples where bounded space is not compact?

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial. The interval $(0,1)$ is bounded but it is not compact

Comment: Heine-Borel gives that closed and bounded $\iff$ compact for subsets of Euclidean space. If we're looking specifically at bounded subsets of Euclidean space, then the compact sets are just the closed sets, so any non-closed set gives you a bounded-noncompact set.

Comment: On the other hand, any compact metric space is bounded. The term "bounded" doesn't really make sense for a topological space that is not a metric space.  There are compact topological spaces that are not metric spaces.

Comment: If $X$ is an infinite space with the discrete metric, then $X$ is bounded but not compact. Moreover, **every** metric space, compact or not, has a bounded metric that generates the same topology.